# Add top padding Dynamically based on view port height

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to set padding dynamically based on the view port height to the "child" div so that the top-padding is 5%  of the view port height.

```
<div id="about-us">Some content
 <div class="child">Other content</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1qp9o42/)

Comment: `padding-top:5vh` http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#about-us .child').css('padding-top', $(window).height() * 0.05);    
});
```

`$(window).height()` will get the height of the viewport and multiplying it by 0.05 will get its 5%

Answer (score 2):

You could use the unit `vh`that is based in viewport height: [info](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/viewport.html)

```
.child {
  padding-top: 5vh;
}
```